# How to place 2 buttons in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, button

I'm building a very simple site it has a header and 2 buttons on it with links when you click the buttons.

I don't know how to place the buttons. Right now they are both displaying next to each other on the left side of the screen just under my header. I want them to display in the middle of the screen next to each other with about 100 pixels between them. I saw a post where you can put one button in the middle of the screen but it doesn't solve the 2 button issue with spacing.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New Unit</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="terminal_banner"> New Unit Landing Page </div>
        <a href="#" class="button1">Button</a>
        <a href="#" class="button1">Button</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>New Unit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="website1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="terminal_banner"> New Unit Landing Page </div>
  <div align="center" >
    <a href="#" class="button1">Button</a> <!-- &nbsp;  &nbsp; -->
     <br>
    <a href="#" class="button1">Button</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Close that got them in the middle but how do i move them down so they are always in the middle of the screen? I guess i could just make a bunch of divs but surely there is a more elegant way? Sorry I'm very much so still learning.

Comment: look for tag  `<br>`

Comment: That is super handy! BR is like page break or the equivalent of enter?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center both vertically and horizontally at all times (even when re-sizing the window):

```
<body>
    <div style="position:fixed; bottom:50%; left:50%">
        <button>Button</button>
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This was the best thing I think I have learned today. I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<div id="terminal_banner"> New Unit Landing Page </div>
<div class=button-wrap>
    <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
</div>

.button-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 50px;
}
```